# TypeScript: how to access the field of an object through a key stored in a variable?

Tags: typescript

```
var obj = {'name':'asdf'};
    var s = 'name';
    alert(obj[s]);
```

This code works fine in JS, but how do I implement it in TS?

Comment: It works exactly the same way in Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact same code will work in TypeScript.

If what you want is to make sure `s` will be a key of `obj` you can use the following:

```
var s: keyof typeof obj = 'name';
```

This will only allow `s` to be one of the keys of `obj`